# Why does Xcode warn me about title shadow offsets in xib files even though I'm targeting iPhone OS 3.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, warnings, xib

When I build my iPhone project, I get warnings from xcode about a few of my xibs saying:

> `Specifying a title shadow offset in
>   Interface Builder is not supported by
>   the iPhone SDK for iPhone OS versions
>   prior to 3.0.`

Thing is, I'm building for 3.0, and the base SDK is set to 3.0. I've done some poking around and can't find anything that looks like it would solve the problem.

I've done some Googling and searched Apple's dev forums and haven't found anything. Does anyone here have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to make sure the deployment target is set to 3.0 in IB as well.

In Interface Builder, go to Window > Document Info and make sure the Deployment Target there is set to iPhone OS 3.0.

In XCode 4.2, you can select the Nib, then open the File Inspector (View > Utilities > File Inspector). Under the Interface Builder Document section, you will a Deployment dropdown.

Comment: Now I'm wondering, is there any way to change the deployment target in all my xibs at once? or do i have to go through all my xibs one by one?

Comment: @Martin Gordon, there is no Window > Document Info in XCode 4.2, do you know how to solve this in XCode 4.2?